# R Keras EarlyStopping cannot coerce type environment to vector of type integer

Tags: r, keras, early-stopping

Developing a Deep Learning with R Keras, and I want to implement earlystopping callback but it displays an error: `Error in as.integer(verbose) :  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'integer'`

The R code:

```
# Compiling the model
model %>% compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
                  optimizer = "adam",
                  
                  metrics = c("accuracy"))

history <- model %>% 
  fit(x_train,
      y_train,
      epoch = 250,
      batch_size = 32,
      callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", 
                              min_delta = 0.001, 
                              patience = 5,
                              restore_best_weights = TRUE,
                              verbose = 1),
      validation_split = 0.2
      )
```

Any idea what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I think that the callbacks argument inside `fit` needs to call a list, something like `callbacks = list(early_stopping)`. Try that and see if it works

Comment: Thanks @JonathanV.Solórzano. You were right, it needs a list inside fit call. `callbacks <- list(  callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss", min_delta = 0.001,               patience = 5,restore_best_weights = TRUE,verbose = 1))` and then, `..fit(... callback=callbacks)`